# Robust way to calculate P&L for stocks/futures trading

Tags: equities, futures

I have implemented a class in C# that will calculate P&L based on [this description](https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/help/fix-adapter-reference/pl-calculation-algorithm/understanding-pl-calculations/) from TT. However it worries me that it gives different results for the same fills, if you apply the "fill download" calculations vs if you simply add fills (example below).

Is there a clear reference resource for P&L calculation? Google has failed me significantly on this one. I am including the code in case this can give an insight to a bug.

```
public sealed class ProfitLoss
{
    public double Realized { get; private set; }

    public int Net { get; private set; }

    public double AverageOpenPrice { get; private set; }

    public ProfitLoss()
    {

    }

    public ProfitLoss(IEnumerable<Tuple<int, double>> initial)
    {
        int buyQuantity = 0, sellQuantity = 0;
        double averageBuyPrice = 0, averageSellPrice = 0;
        foreach (var fill in initial)
        {
            if (fill.Item1 > 0)
            {
                buyQuantity += fill.Item1;
                averageBuyPrice += fill.Item1 * fill.Item2;
            }
            else if (fill.Item1 < 0)
            {
                int absQuantity = Math.Abs(fill.Item1);
                sellQuantity += absQuantity;
                averageSellPrice += absQuantity * fill.Item2;
            }
        }

        if (buyQuantity > 0)
            averageBuyPrice /= buyQuantity;
        if (sellQuantity > 0)
            averageSellPrice /= sellQuantity;

        Net = buyQuantity - sellQuantity;
        AverageOpenPrice = Net > 0 ? averageBuyPrice : averageSellPrice;
        Realized = (averageSellPrice - averageBuyPrice) * Math.Min(buyQuantity, sellQuantity);
    }

    public void AddFill(int quantity, double price)
    {
        if (quantity == 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(quantity), "Quantity must be non-zero.");

        if (Math.Sign(Net) != Math.Sign(quantity))
        {
            int absNet = Math.Abs(Net);
            int absQuantity = Math.Abs(quantity);

            if (absNet == absQuantity) // flat
            {
                Realized += (price - AverageOpenPrice) * Net;
                AverageOpenPrice = 0;
            }
            else if (absNet > absQuantity) // decrease
            {
                Realized += (price - AverageOpenPrice) * -quantity;
            }
            else // reverse
            {
                Realized += (price - AverageOpenPrice) * Net;
                AverageOpenPrice = price;
            }
        }
        else // increase position
        {
            AverageOpenPrice = (Net * AverageOpenPrice + quantity * price) / (Net + quantity);
        }

        Net += quantity;
    }

    public double FloatingForTheoriticalExit(double exitPrice)
    {
        return (exitPrice - AverageOpenPrice) * Net;
    }
}
```

Example of difference in calculation:

```
new ProfitLoss(new[] {
    Tuple.Create(12, 100.0),
    Tuple.Create(17, 99.0),
    Tuple.Create(-9, 101.0),
    Tuple.Create(-4, 105.0),
    Tuple.Create(3, 103.0)
}).Dump();
```

Yields:

```
Realized 32.2499999999999 
Net 19 
AverageOpenPrice 99.75
```

But

```
var calc = new ProfitLoss();
calc.AddFill(12, 100);
calc.AddFill(17, 99);
calc.AddFill(-9, 101);
calc.AddFill(-4, 105);
calc.AddFill(3, 103);
calc.Dump();
```

Yields:

```
Realized 36.6206896551725 
Net 19 
AverageOpenPrice 99.9800362976407
```

Comment: @AlexC I've looked at this several times now and I can't see a difference in order between the two examples. Can you please be specific? And thank you for the clarification but, if that is the case, how does a broker calculate the money in your account until the moment you are completely flat in terms of positioning??

Comment: Sorry, my previous two suggestions are not useful. I have deleted them.

Comment: @AlexC I think you may be right after all. If I add another fill to flatten the positions, both cases yield the same Realized PnL.

Answer (score 1):

After @AlexC's suggestion I tried adding fills to flatten the net positioning and the two calculations do indeed return the same output in terms of Realized PnL:

```
new ProfitLoss(new[] {
    new Fill(12, 100.0),
    new Fill(17, 99.0),
    new Fill(-9, 101.0),
    new Fill(-4, 105.0),
    new Fill(3, 103.0),
    new Fill(-19, 100)
}).Dump();

var calc = new ProfitLoss();
calc.AddFill(12, 100);
calc.AddFill(17, 99);
calc.AddFill(-9, 101);
calc.AddFill(-4, 105);
calc.AddFill(3, 103);
calc.AddFill(-19, 100);
calc.Dump();
```

Both of the above yield a Realized PnL of 37.